# MSYS2 bash readline command not found

Tags: windows, bash, shell, mingw-w64, msys2

I installed MSYS2 under Windows 7. I want to build an open source project which requires readline. I installed readline with

```
pacman -S libreadline
```

But when I want to *configure*, it stops with error stating that it can't find readline.

```
configure: error: --with-readline was given, but test for readline failed
```

Also when I run from bash

```
readline -v
```

It says *'bash: readline: command not found'*.

<s>I did same under mingw64 shell, first installing packages with mingw-w64-x86_64 prefix, including package mingw-w64-x86_64-readline.</s>

Here outputs are the same.

I was able to *configure* same source with Cygwin readline package (though I failed to *make* later).

Why does MSYS2 shell can't find readline command? Can you help me overcoming this problem?

Comment: `readline` isn't a command. So you can't `readline -v` to see anything useful. You probably installed the library but not the header files. See if there is a `-dev` or `-devel` version of the package also.

Comment: @EtanReisner Thank you, that solved the problem. When I installed the libreadline-devel package, it was able to *configure*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readline` isn't a command so you can't `readline -v` to see anything useful.

You probably installed the library but not the header files.

See if there is a `-dev` or `-devel` version of the package also.